# Share files between free and paid app

Tags: ios, file, share

We have a paid app on the App Store with id following the lines of com.company.client and we want to add a free version, optimally with the id of com.company.client.free. I need to figure out how, if a user buys the paid app after using the free one, they can get their data from the free version into the paid one... I recall reading somewhere this was possible but I can't for the life of me find it in the apple documentation. I vaguely remember it had to do with the app's bundle ID and using a wild card, but since we already have a version on the app store that we can't change, I don't know how that would affect it. Any help or links to proper documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share keychain data between applications in the same family. I would however only recommend this for small user data such as passwords, username etc.

See this guide on how to do that:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/03/keychain-group-access.html

For heavier data, I recommend that you use an online service with user accounts to share the data between your apps. (as mentioned by Clafou, iCloud might help you here for iOS5 and above)

A third option for you could be to make the paid version free, and then use add in-app-purchase for the paid content. But maybe that could cause problems like how to handle the users that have already paid for your app.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of, but apparently I was wrong in thinking documents could be moved through the system this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement and am yet to try this out, but if you are happy to use iCloud then you could use the same iCloud identifier (which is different to your Bundle IDs) in both versions of your app so that the data could be sync'ed across devices and across your app versions (paid and free).

Comment: While this is what I was trying to avoid (using iCloud) it seems to be the only option other than creating a forwarding system that the user can trigger to export the content from the free app into the paid one (which is just bad UX).